# Windows have pinstripes and large corner radius on Lion

Tags: macos, ui

Somehow, some `defaults` setting or something in Lion on my MacBook Pro has gotten set terribly wrong, because starting recently, my inactive windows (and certain other window chrome) have gained what I presume to be 10.4 Tiger-style pinstripes.

Behold the horror:

[image: Pinstripes on inactive windows]

[image: Pinstripes on dialog boxes]

Obviously, this is **not acceptable in any way**. I don't know what I did that made these appear. I've looked through [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com/), but haven't found anything relevant. Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:** I just realized that in addition to the pinstripes, windows' corner radii have grown larger, as they were in Tiger and before, as well. What in the world is going on?

Comment: Not gonna lie, I quite like them myself.

Comment: Is it possible that you installed anything to change OS X's appearance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I overlooked the two checkboxes in Secrets depicted below (even though their labels were red and in bold and they are obviously in every way exactly what I was looking for). The second one, "Use Leopard window values", was unchecked. Checking it and rebooting restored all windows to their normal appearance. Phew.

[image]